# Using replace instead of find

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written the following piece but not able to figure the next part:

```
if request.guess in game.target:            
  position = game.target.find(request.guess)
  game.correct[position] = request.guess.upper()
```

The point here is `request.guess` is a character input like `'a'` and `game.target` is `'austin'`. So the above code will find the character in the target word and generate an output like `a*****`. But my code will only work for words that have letters not repeated in them eg: Australia. I know there is a method 'replace' in python but I am not able to figure out how should I incorporate here.

Kindly help!!!!!

Comment: You know there is a `replace` but don't know how to use it? A tutorial will help you more than any answer to your question.

Comment: Iterate over the characters in `game.target` using `for i, c in enumerate(game.target)`.  Inside the loop, you have access to both the caharacter `c` and its position `i`.  Check whether `c` matches the guessed character, and if it does, update the displayed string at position `i`.

Comment: @SSNR: The problem here is game.correct is variable with *****, so i am not sure how to get the position for the repeated letters and then replace the same. So if you could help then that would be great

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Thank you very much. Your trick did the work. Thanks a ton!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

just use a set of guessed letters and do something like the below.

```
In [164]: word = 'Australia'
In [165]: guessed = set()
In [166]: guessed.add('a')
In [167]: print(''.join(c if c.lower() in guessed else '*' for c in word))
A****a**a
```

Answer (score 1):

With regular expressions:

```
import re
correct = re.sub(r'[^a]',"*","australia")  # returns "a****a**a"
```

This the regular expression `[^a]` matches all characters except "a". The `re.sub` function replaces each "not a" with a "*"

*edit*

Your comments make be think that you are trying to change the `game.correct` string by replacing characters in that string. Remember that strings in python are immutable. You can't change individual letters in them. So rather than try to change the stars to "a", you have to make a new string. Regular expressions are one way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`replace` will not help here, since you are not changing the string you are searching.

There are two options here:

1. Use `str.find` repeatedly:

   ```
   pos = 0
   while True:
       pos = game.target.find(request.guess, start=pos)
       if pos == -1: break
       game.correct[pos] = request.guess.upper()
   ```
2. Build the string from scratch each time:

   ```
   game.correct = ''.join(
       letter if letter in request.guesses else '*'
       for letter in game.target
   )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you invest some time in learning [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), they come in handy in many similar situations and are often more expressive (and efficient) than ad-hoc implementations. Plus you can reuse (with some quirks) your understanding of them in other languages and OS shells, which makes them very powerful.

You can build a regular expression from your pattern that will match anything except the characters you are looking for: `r'[^{}]'.format(pattern)`; then use it to do the substitution:

```
import re
pattern = request.guess
result = re.sub(r'[^{}]'.format(pattern),"*","adam")
```

[Example on IdeOne](https://ideone.com/7eDYFz):

```
import re
print re.sub(r'[^{}]'.format('ad'),"*","adam")
print re.sub(r'[^{}]'.format('a'),"*","adam")
print re.sub(r'[^{}]'.format('m'),"*","adam")
```

Prints:

```
ada*
a*a*
***m
```